# cURL set max filesize

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl, filesize

I'm trying to download a file using curl, but it seems to fail at a file with the size of 1.48MB. It just downloads a very small file that is broken. A (eg) 209kb large file works fine though.

Command used: `curl -H 'Authorization: token mygithubauthkey' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' -O -L https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/therepo/contents/target/thejar.jar`

This commands works fine if I for example download a small txt file. So it's most likely caused the the size of the jar (smaller .jar's work fine as well)

Anybody got ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should edit your answer to include the actual curl command used and the output of that command.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Done.

Comment: @DanielStenberg Yep, when I download a smaller file it gives me the same output as if I were to download a file that (apparently) is too large. It just says that the larger (too large) file is a few kb large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a GitHub Issue. They only allow a filesize up to 1MB for those types of downloads.